# Directly downwind faster than wind

Tags: classical-mechanics, aerodynamics

I have recently come across a land vehicle called Blackbird, the inventor of which claims that it can run directly downwind faster than wind.
It is sponsored by Google and there were some tests which showed that the vehicle can run up to 2.8 times the windspeed.

I find it really interesting so I did some search about the topic on the internet. After reading several articles and forum threads related to the topic, I am still confused about how it exactly works.

To begin with, the explanation of the team that built the vehicle can be summed up as follows: wind pushes the frame of the car, which makes the wheels roll, the wheels then rotate the propeller, the propeller extract wind power to produce thrust that drives the car forward.
How can a propeller do such thing? How can it use power out of the wind to create thrust in a direction opposite to the wind?

Secondly, I have also looked at some formulas that are claimed to be the description of how the vehicle works. One formula (from a professor named Mark Drela) shows zero propeller power when the vehicle speed equals wind speed, so apparently the vehicle could not exceed wind speed, but it could still accelerates given it is already at a speed greater than wind speed. How could it reach 2.8 times the wind speed in the test?

This confusion also led me to doubt the actual test itself, so I searched further and found a thread on international skeptics forum, in which there are some who critized the way the data was measured and processed. In particular, the measurement data was processed by the inventors, not by a third party, which raises doubts about transparency, the placement of measurement instrument and data processing after the test could also hide gust and change in wind direction (making it not directly downwind). Why couldn't they just test in a wind tunnel?

Could someone explain whether this works. If so, what is wrong in my understanding of the way it works?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate of, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/931/25301

Comment: I have read that and think it does not have a correct/full explanation.

Comment: The physics behind it is perfectly solid. Oddly enough, I think the best explanation for it anywhere on the internet is from the official solutions to a physics competition that asked precisely this as a question; see [here](https://www.aapt.org/physicsteam/2019/upload/USAPhO-2013-Solutions.pdf).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sail downwind faster than the wind?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/931/)

Comment: @tlong: *I have read that and think it does not have a correct/full explanation.* If you think the answers there are wrong or incomplete, you could say that in comments on those answers. But in general it's not a good idea on SE to start a new question because you aren't convinced by the answers to an old question.

Comment: I want to start a new question because my question is not exactly the same, the other question was about the general mechanics of the vehicle, but here I address only some details of the mechanics and the validity of the test run.