# Can an system (wind sail) move faster than the speed of the wind in the ground reference frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow, aerodynamics

I just mean to be simple here, there are numerous articles on this platform itself regarding the exact topic and other information outside but I wanted to cover up the insight that I got here.
After watching the video made by great youtuber derek (channel name:- veritasium) he covered a topic over this but somewhere in the second half he mentioned an important thing that the vehicle (so called blackbird) does not works like a windmill (that is the wheels help the movement of the flaps) and this niche change made him give an explanation.
So I went ahead having a similar kind of theoretical machine in which instead of that arrangements the the flaps move the wheels and as just being a body with wheels it will move under the influence of wind getting a head start and after achieving certain velocity as the flaps are at an angle to the wind they will move fast thus making a non electrical machine move faster than wind by which it is propelled. ( As a system can move faster at an angle and as the flaps are at an certain angle they move faster than the wind and thus blowing away the particles of air behind to get acceleration).
I still do not feel any good about this, I do feel that a machine like this will just not be possible or would even convert that heat in heat energy not to cross that limit. I don't understand that why it isn't possible.

I feel like making absurd mistake.

Link to the video, https://youtu.be/jyQwgBAaBag

Comment: First of all, please post a drawing of your design so we can understand what your "flaps" look like and their mechanical linkage.

Comment: duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/639993/

Answer (score 0):

The "blackbird" is one of many designs which use a "pinwheel" or propellor design geared to the wheels to achieve  DDFTTW.
Despite all the angry heat and venom posted by people who think they know physics but refuse to analyze the situation (probably the same people who deny the Monte Hall Problem!),  the physics behind this craft is well-understood and completely valid.